# External hard drive formating and partitioning

Tags: hard-drive

I have external drive of 1 TB.The drive is formated as FAT32 for the data I need(around 400 GB).Now I want to create a new partition(without loosing my fat32 data) but I want it NTFS so it can hold files larger than 4GB.When I go to diskmanagement the shrink expand or anything else options are greyed out..any ideas?!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a tool called "GParted".  It's a Linux based tool that should let you edit and create partitions.  Once you get gparted running, right click on the existing partition and shrink it.  Then in the "Unallocated Space" right click and select "Create new partition" and set it to NTFS as large as you want.

Don't forget to click the "Apply" button, Gparted queues up all the commands then runs them in order when you click apply.  Also note that resizing partitions can take a long time, it might give you a warning about not being bootable, but assuming this isn't your boot drive, it shouldn't be an issue.  Also be sure you have the correct drive selected in the top right corner of gparted, in the image below /dev/hda is selected.

Instructions for getting GParted running on a USB flash drive: http://gparted.org/liveusb.php

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows DiskManagement is limited in its capabilities. Try using other partitioning software. I would recommend Gparted.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_partitioning_software